# Blank white screen on localhost:3000 in my react project

Tags: reactjs, jsx, rendering, react-functional-component

I am getting blank white screen on localhost:3000 in my React project. The components dont get rendered. I guess the issue is with one component, because when i comment out that component(SearchForm.js) from JSX, the other components do show up. Kindly highlight what could be the possiblities causing the issue. Thanks

SearchForm.js

```
import { Form, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function SearchForm({ params, onParamChange }) {
  return (
    <Form className="mb-4">
      <Form.Row className="align-items-end">
        <Form.Group as={Col}>
          <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control onChange={onParamChange} value={params.description} name="description" type="text" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Col}>
          <Form.Label>Location</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control onChange={onParamChange} value={params.location} name="location" type="text" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Col} xs="auto" className="ml-2">
          <Form.Check onChange={onParamChange} value={params.full_time} name="full_time" id="full-time" label="Only Full Time" type="checkbox" className="mb-2" />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form.Row>
    </Form>
  )
}

App.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useFetchJobs from './useFetchJobs'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Job from './Job'
import JobsPagination from './JobsPagination';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm';

function App() {
  const [params, setParams] = useState({})
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const { jobs, loading, error, hasNextPage } = useFetchJobs(params, page)

  function handleParamChange(e) {
    const param = e.target.name
    const value = e.target.value
    setPage(1)
    setParams(prevParams => {
      return { ...prevParams, [param]: value }
    })
  }

  return (
    <Container className="my-4">
      <h1 className="mb-4">GitHub Jobs</h1>
      <SearchForm params={params} onParamChange={handleParamChange} />
      <JobsPagination page={page} setPage={setPage} hasNextPage={hasNextPage} />
      {loading && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
      {error && <h1>Error. Try Refreshing.</h1>}
      {jobs.map(job => {
        return <Job key={job.id} job={job} />
      })}
      <JobsPagination page={page} setPage={setPage} hasNextPage={hasNextPage} />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems okay, will need more information, Like how did you import and use it in another file.

Comment: Sure, it is default export so imported to App.js without {}, I've added code for App.js where SearchForm in imported.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After trying it out, I decided to just import { Row } directly from react-bootstrap.

But if you would like to continue with Form.Row, try checking how you imported bootstrap in index.js

> import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";